# Can we use Tor in Python program?

Tags: python, windows, ip, tor

I try to use or change IP address and do web scraping on public data accessible by all but I can't find a solution. I am trying to do a rotating ip address. I'm on Windows 10 and the Anaconda IDE.
For example, i execute this code below:

```
import requests

domain = "https://www.undernews.fr"
#define your proxies
#the socks5h method allows the socks server to translate the #hostname. So make sure that you add 'socks5h'.
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}
a = requests.get(domain.strip(), proxies=proxies).text
print(a)
```

And my kernel return:

```
  File "C:\Users\FirstName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.undernews.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CF0D4EA3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those proxies have been blocked:

Translated part of your error:
"No connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it"

Maybe try looking into using [proxyscrape](https://pypi.org/project/proxyscrape/) to get a list of "free" proxies. Or at least try with a different proxy IP